# Background removal software with Red, Green selection algorithms

Tags: image-processing, image-editor

I have found some web based background removal software that seem to use a cool algorithm.

These web apps have a green brush and red brush.

If you paint something with a green brush the selection and the adjacent pixels similar to the ones you painted will not be removed.

If you paint an object with the red brush, say the background the pixels adjacent and similar to the selection will be removed.

This is one of those apps, but can handle only small images, prolly due to server limitations.

http://editphotosforfree.com/photoapps/remove-background-from-image-online/

Now, I want a free app that is either cloud based or Windows or Linux or Android based.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite the same as your requested algorithm but a great way to something similar is with [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) to use the heal tool, *(a separate plugin install from [here](http://registry.gimp.org/node/27986))*, which actually fills in the removed area with copies from the surrounding area. You simply select the area that you wish to remove, (by drawing or colour selection), and select Filters, Enhance, Heal Selection.

GIMP is free, (Gratis & Open Source), and available to run on Windows, Linux & Mac.

As an example I took this photo from Barbados:
[image]
Then thought shame about the people & the crane, a quick couple of minutes later got:
[image]
The results aren't perfect but if I took a little more time it could be fantastic.

Comment: I already know about GIMP but I was looking for a native version of the algorithm I mentioned.

Comment: @Kotlinboy: What do you mean by "native" in this context? - The only true native windows image manipulation program is MS Paint (which is native in that it comes with Windows).

Comment: Like not web or cloud based and runs natively on desktop. Hell even an Android version is fine. Most of these cloud based versions are asking for money.

Comment: @Kotlinboy - GIMP is ___not___ a web based solution it runs directly on your machine once installed with no internet connection used post install. _In fact if you download the installer for your platform(s) you can install from a USB key to machines that do not have a net connection. It is also __completely free___.